# How could bpmn service task send messages to WSO2 ESB in WSO2 BPS

Tags: wso2, activiti, bpmn, wso2-business-process, wso2-esb

I know a service task of BPMN can send messages (JMS or WS calls) to external system using camel or mule in Activiti, but it seems that there's no camel or mule supported in WSO2 BPS, and I'm afraid it is because WSO2 ESB can substitute for them. So, my question is how can a service task send messages to WSO2 EBS?

Obviously, I can create a Java class implementing JavaDelegate class for a service task and write some codes for sending messages in execute method, but I want to know whether there's some "smart" solution..

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

BPMN service task would be the solution in this case as you have mentioned. What type of service call do you need to do in ESB? If it's a REST API invoke in ESB, you could use the REST TASK extension available in WSO2 BPS. You could find a good use case on this in [example](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2016/04/article-how-to-model-bpmn-business-processes-with-wso2-business-process-server/)

For example, you could add a Service Task with                                           Task Type: Java Class
Class Name: org.wso2.carbon.bpmn.extensions.rest.RESTTask
with following fields.

- serviceURL - rest service endpoint
- method - http method to use
- basicAuthUsername - username if the endpoints are secured
- basicAuthPassword - password for the username above
- input - payload to be sent
- outputVariable - process variable to save the response
- header values in the format "key1:value1,key2:value2"

Comment: Sorry for late reply and thanks for your kind information. Actually, RESTful api or we can say HTTP calls is one method that let BPMN processes communicate to outside. But it is a type of synchronous calls, and always waits for the response. I just want to use asynchronous calls like JMS or AMQP or etc. for some cases. And in fact, I also want to know is there any method to integrate the WSO2 BPS and ESB?